# Why are my wolves completely white?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image: A screenshot I took of the white wolves.. Can anyone help me out?]

I have no idea how to fix this, and I am not using textures/mods. I am on the latest version, as well.
(Note: That Parrot beside the wolf is from the newest update. This is not a mod.)

Comment: Does the same happens if you spawn a wolf in 1.12.1?

Comment: Why did you accept the wrong answer? It's factually wrong, it's a random guess instead of an answer and it has a score of -3, which automatically greys it out.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I would think that your wolf texture is missing. Try looking for it in your textures folder. Otherwise, I've got no idea :|

Comment: A missing texture is pink/black, not white.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can imagine is a texture in a resource pack. Try going to options->resource packs and disabling everything on the right (except for the default textures of course).